# ROM 4kx8 verilog, problem with reading file with $readmemb

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to implement 4kx8 ROM in Verilog.  I used `$readmemb` to read a .list file with initial values ​​for the ROM.  The problem is that in the .list I put a "jump" for the address like this:

```
0000_0001
0000_0010
0000_0011
0000_0100
@ 55
0000_0101
0000_0110
0000_0111
@ 60
0000_1000
0000_1001
@ 100
0000_1010
```

When I read the four initial values, that's okay. But when I read the 55,56,57,60,61 and 100 address, the monitor shows me xxxxxxxx. I tried write address in hex, binary and decimal but nothing happen.  That's my module and testbench:

```
module ROMmemory(input [11:0]direccion, output reg [7:0]salida);
    reg [7:0] memoria [0:4096];
    initial begin
        $readmemb("rom2.list",memoria);
    end
    always @ (*) begin
        salida<=memoria[direccion];
    end
endmodule
```

testbench:

```
reg [11:0]direccion;
wire [7:0]valores;
ROMmemory RM(direccion,valores);
initial begin
        $display("\n");
        $display("ROM 4kx8");
        $display("address   |    values");
        $display("-------------------|---");
        $monitor("%b | %b", direccion,valores);
        #180 direccion=1;
        #1 direccion=2;
        #1 direccion=3;
        #1 direccion='d30;
        #1 direccion='d31;
        #1 direccion='d85;
        #1 direccion=85;
        #1 direccion='h55;
        #1 direccion=61;
        #10 $finish;

    end
```

i started 180 times after because i have other module before ROM.

the monitor show me this:

```
ROM 4kx8
address   |    values
-------------|---
VCD info: dumpfile Ejercicio1_tb.vcd opened for output.
000000000000 | 00000001
000000000001 | 00000010
000000000010 | 00000011
000000000011 | 00000100
000000011110 | xxxxxxxx
000000011111 | xxxxxxxx
000001010101 | xxxxxxxx
000000111101 | xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simulator generates a warning message:

```
xmsim: *W,RMEMSYN: $readmem error: invalid syntax in file "rom2.list" at line 5.
```

This is the line:

```
@ 55
```

When I remove the space between `@` and `55`, the warning goes away:

```
0000_0001
0000_0010
0000_0011
0000_0100
@55
0000_0101
0000_0110
0000_0111
@60
0000_1000
0000_1001
@100
0000_1010
```

Now, I don't get `x` at `'h55`:

```
000001010101 | 00000101
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.4 *Loading memory array data from a file*:

> No white space is allowed between the @ and the number.